# JsPlumb Recreate Canvas Using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, dom, jsplumb

I use a function called "initJsPlumb" to create diagram and send it to  my ajax data  which includes route and node informations as parameter.In this function,I generate instance, connections and nodes placement.

The problem is:
A selectbox triggers ajax and gets datas from controller and try to reacreate jsplumb.When i change selectbox ,first using `$("#canvas").empty();` and get datas from controller and then recreate diagram with  `initJsPlumb(data);` .After that, all nodes and connections create correctly.But when i use `instance.getConnections()` to get all nodes positions its give me old connections list(before call ajax) or i use `instance.getAllConnections()` its give me correct connections but when write them to console and mouse over on the nodes on console, cannot reach html elements so i cant get their top,left position informations(they are always 0).

Anyone has solutions to solve reset and recreate jsplumb?

Answer (score 0):

If you empty out the container jsPlumb is using without telling it jsPlumb will get in a muddle.  You should probably call `reset()` on the jsPlumb instance, or in fact just create a whole new instance.